# Convergence of solutions to a ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For the following system

$$ \frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{1}{g(t)} , y(0)= y_0$$
$$ \frac{dz}{dt} = -\frac{1}{y(t)} , z(\infty)=0$$

where $g(t) > 0$ is defined on $[0,\infty]$. Is there any way to find necessary (or even sufficient) conditions for existence of convergent solutions for $z(t)$ ?

Comment: You'd better have $g(t) > 0$ on all of $[0,\infty)$ if you want the first equation well-defined all the way from $t=0$ to $\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $ \dfrac{dz}{dt} = - \frac{1}{y(t)}$ and $\lim_{t \to +\infty} z(t) = 0$, you must have

$$ z(t) = \int_t^\infty \frac{ds}{y(s)}$$
and this must be a convergent improper integral.  A sufficient condition for convergence is that for some $C > 0$ and $p > 1$, 
$y(s) > C s^{p}$ for all sufficiently large $s$.  A necessary condition is that for every $C > 0$, there exist arbitrarily large $s$ such that $y(s) > C s$,

Now you also have

$$ y(s) = y_0 + \int_{0}^s \dfrac{dt}{g(t)} $$

This will satisfy the sufficient condition if for some $C >0$ and $p > 1$, $0 < g(t) < C t^{1-p}$ for all sufficiently large $t$.  On the other hand, a necessary condition for the previous necessary condition is that $\liminf_{s \to \infty} g(s) = 0$.